# Не могу подключиться к серверам юнити

Tags: unity3d

Пишет "cannot get revision from server", при этом входит на аккаунт спокойно. Загрузить проект на другой пк не могу из за этой ошибки.

Comment: Такая же проблема уже неделю.... интересно когда исправится ситуация

Answer (score 1):

Точно такая же проблема со вчерашнего дня. Судя по всему, это связанно с блокировкой роскомнадзором серверов амазона и гугла.